# Google Cloud Build non-shell secret substitution

Tags: google-cloud-build

I am deploying a cloud function with secret env variables that I would like to add to the function. From the [example](https://cloud.google.com/cloud-build/docs/securing-builds/use-encrypted-secrets-credentials#example_build_request_using_an_encrypted_variable) it mentions that that "# Note: You need a shell to resolve environment variables with $$".

I am using the gcloud builder, which seems to not be a shell so my environment variables are just `$USER` and `$PASS` literally without substitution. I've tried `$USER` and `${USER}` as well but it complains about not having valid substitutions.

**How do I get my secrets from the google cloud build environment into my google cloud function environment?**

The first step is to verify that my KMS stuff is working, which it appears to be.

```
  - name: 'ubuntu'
    args: ['printenv']
    secretEnv: ['USER','PASS']
  - name: "gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud"
    args:
      [
        "functions",
        "deploy",
        "fname",
        "--trigger-http",
        "--runtime=nodejs10",
        "--service-account=functions-secrets@northpoint-production.iam.gserviceaccount.com",
        "--set-env-vars=USER=$$USER,PASS=$$PASS",
        "--entry-point=fname",
        "--project=[project]",
      ]
    dir: "functions"
    secretEnv: ['USER','PASS']
secrets:
- kmsKeyName: projects/[project]/locations/global/keyRings/[ring]/cryptoKeys/[key]
  secretEnv:
    USER: CiQAML6I...
    PASS: CiQAML6IGO3wO...
```

Comment: Your `USER=$$USER}` is strange? Wrong copy paste or you forgot the brace?

Comment: wrong copy, updated!

Answer (score 3):

You are missing the **entrypoint: 'bash'** part per the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/cloud-build/docs/securing-builds/use-encrypted-secrets-credentials#example_build_request_using_an_encrypted_variable) you shared.

```
steps:
  - name: "gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud"
    entrypoint: "bash"
    args:
           [
    "-c",
    "gcloud functions deploy fname --trigger-http --runtime=nodejs10 --service-account=[account] --set-env-vars=USER=$$USER,PASS=$$PASS --entry-point=fname --project=[project]",
  ]
    dir: "functions"
    secretEnv: ["USER", "PASS"]
secrets:
  - kmsKeyName: projects/[project]/locations/global/keyRings/[ring]/cryptoKeys/[key]
    secretEnv:
      USER: CiQAML...
      PASS: CiQAML...
```

Comment: It's not the same. But don't worry, not the issue. All look good, don't understand

Comment: Thanks! you helped me figure out the right direction and I added correct code for future viewers.

Comment: Actually I take that back, the substitution works but is still only passing `$USER`. @AndresS do you have any recommendations on how to edit my code?

Comment: turns out it is essential to use a single command, updated the correct code.